# ggplot2: Plotting two models with regression coefficients

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to replicate the figure below with `ggplot2` (though larger, I don't know why the figure is so small here).

[image: Original graph developed in Stata]

(The subject of this research is the integration of Muslim minority youth.)

I developed the original figure above with the package -coefplot- in Stata and now try to the same in R.

In R and `ggplot2`, I start with two simple data frames obtained with `MplusAutomation` (from estimates in the Mplus application). The data frames can be reproduces with the following code:

```
resModel1 <- 
  structure(list(param = c("FEMALE", "CHRISTIAN", "MUSLIM"), 
  low2.5 = c(-0.436, 0.038, 0.19), 
  est = c(-0.271, 0.18, 0.354), up2.5 = c(-0.106, 0.323, 0.519)), 
  .Names = c("param", "low2.5", "est", "up2.5"), row.names = 7:9, 
  class = c("data.frame", "mplus.params"))

resModel2 <- 
  structure(list(param = c("FEMALE", "CHRISTIAN", "MUSLIM", "CHRISTGI", "MUSLIMGI"), 
  low2.5 = c(-0.672, -0.256, -0.018, 0.131, -0.143), 
  est = c(-0.437, -0.038, 0.237, 0.403, 0.237), up2.5 = c(-0.203,                                                                                 0.18, 0.493, 0.675, 0.617)), .Names = c("param", "low2.5", "est", "up2.5"), 
  row.names = 7:11, class = c("data.frame", "mplus.params"))
```

I then try to develop two plots with `ggplot2` and to combine them with `gridExtra`:

```
library(ggplot2)
limits <- aes(ymax  = up2.5, ymin = low2.5) 

plot1 <- ggplot(resModel1, aes(x=param, y=est)) + 
  geom_pointrange(limits, color = "darkblue") + 
  scale_x_discrete("") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, color="red") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=10)) +
  ylab(NULL) + 
  coord_flip() 

plot2 <- ggplot(resModel2, aes(x=param, y=est)) + 
  geom_pointrange(limits, color="darkblue") + 
  scale_x_discrete("") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, color="red") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=10)) +
  ylab(NULL) + 
  coord_flip()

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ncol=2)
```

... and end up with the following plot:

[image]

I was hoping to do the following:

1. Sort coefficients by hand (in this order: Christian, Muslim, Female)
2. Align coefficients for the same predictor across models (as done in the plot developed in Stata, where "Muslim girls" and "Christian girls" are plotted with no results in Plot1, making all predictors/parameters align across Model1 and Model 2)
3. Include the regression coefficient in the plot (numbers above the dots representing point estimates in the regression analysis).
4. Change names of predictors (e.g., from MUSLIMGI to "Muslim girls"), without editing the data frame.
5. Adjust the x-scale to be the same for the two plots. 
   (Also, name the two models, I assume I should be able to figure out myself how to do that.)

When searching for solutions, I found an R package called `coefplot` (a sort of add-on to `ggplot2`), but I am not sure whether `coefplot` can develop the plot I want and I would like to code things myself in `ggplot2` for flexibility.

I also found `sjp.glm` (https://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2013/03/22/plotting-lm-and-glm-models-with-ggplot-rstats/), but I could not see how that function helps me when I have estimated statistical models outside R and need to plot parameters available in data frames.

Comment: You need to ask just one question at a time. Make a minimal example that focuses on the one thing you need need to do. There are probably existing questions and answers for each of these 5 requests. Hard to point you in the right place when you lump them all together. These questions should help other askers in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think the questions help others developing a similar plot, partly because they will find most/all of their answers at one place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get you started at least, fixing points 1, 2, 3 and 5. Point 4 is undesirable, it is much easier to just edit your data.frame, don't put artificial limitations on yourself.

```
df <- rbind(resModel1, resModel2)
df$model <- rep(c('Model 1', 'Model 2'), c(nrow(resModel1), nrow(resModel2)))
df$param_f <- factor(df$param, 
                     rev(c('CHRISTIAN', 'MUSLIM', 'FEMALE', 'CHRISTGI', 'MUSLIMGI')),
                     rev(c('Christian', 'Muslum', 'Female', 'Christian girls', 'Muslim girls')))

ggplot(df, aes(x = param_f, y = est)) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymax = up2.5, ymin = low2.5), color = "darkblue") +
  geom_text(aes(label = est), nudge_x = 0.15) + 
  scale_x_discrete("") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "red") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=10)) +
  ylab(NULL) + 
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(~model)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Hats off and thank you so much!